# Hide div with jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to hide/show a div for a value selected on a dropdownlist. I've done several changes on my code but I can't solve this. 
I'm new on jquery and I need to know if al functions have to be defined on head or is possible to create functions on body?
Here is my code:

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function notify(selec) {
$("#Q550").hide();
alert( selec );
}
$(document).ready(function(){
var selec = $("#Q1113>option").val();
var selec2 = "Q1113_QO3582";
alert ($('#Q1113').val());
$( "#Q1113" ).on( 'click',notify(selec));

});



</script> 
</head>
```

```
<div class="section row" id="divQ1113" style="display: block;">

<div class="section row principal_question">
    <label>Cual fue su motivo de estancia</label>   </div>

    <div class="section row sub_question">
        </div>

<div class="section row">
    <select name="Q1113" id="Q1113">
        <option value="">Opciones</option>
        <option value="Q1113_QO3417"> </option>
        <option value="Q1113_QO3582">Turismo</option>
        <option value="Q1113_QO3583">Negocios</option>
        <option value="Q1113_QO3584">Familia</option>
</select>   </div>
</div>

<div id="Q550"><label style="text-align: center;">0</label><input value="0"  style="display: block; margin: 9px 0px 0px -2px;" type="radio" name="Q550" id="Q550"></div>
```

Comment: When I select a specific value on the dropdownlist. And it must be shown when this value is not selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can/should be including your javascript libs and code just before the closing `</body>` tag. You also don't need to get the option. i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function notify(selec) {
        $("#Q550").hide();
        alert(selec);
    }

    $("#Q1113").on('click',function() {
       var selectValue = $("#Q550").val();
        notify(selectValue);
    });
});
```

or you can just have the code inline father then a separate function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Q1113").on('click',function() {
       $("#Q550").hide()
       alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

**IF** however you want this to happen when the select value has changed and only on certain values, then you'd need:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Q1113").on('change',function() {

       if ($(this).val() == "SOME VALUE YOU WANT TO SEE") {
           $("#Q550").hide()
           alert($(this).val());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: updated answer. you need to bind to `change` not click. `alert($(this).val());` shows the selected value

Comment: Yes. A specific value.

Comment: Well. It works perfect!!! It works alone but it doesn't work in my whole page. There must be something wrong on my page...

Answer (score 0):

Try hooking into the **change** event of the dropdown control.
See http://api.jquery.com/change/ for API reference.